# 「ので」のように、「のに」も略せますか？

Tags: colloquial-language, particle-の, conjunctions, abbreviations

「ので」が略せるように、接続助詞の「のに」も略せますか？

「ので」が「んで」か、「なんで」か、「なので」になれるなら、

「のに」も「んに」とか、「なんに」とか、「なのに」になれますか？

これを思えば、そうですか？

また、私の日本語がよくなかったら、すみません！

Comment: 「ですの・ますの」なんて言い方、フィクションのお嬢様の役割語です。

Comment: ええ、今に分かって、私のはとてもよくない。。。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

言ったので → 言ったんで

言ったのに → 言ったんに

Very colloquial and informal but possible. But you should avoid this if you are not very fluent speaker.

Comment: いい！分かって。理論に使うって分かったけど、実際使うって分からなかったですよ。

Comment: @Tirous How is this the best answer?

Comment: So you also think these are not possible constructions? Or what?

Answer (score 5):

ならない。

「のに」も「なのに」も「んに」や「なんに」にはならない。

Comment: ですよね～～。「言ったんに」「教師なんに」なんて聞いたことない・・

Comment: 発音のブレをそのまま表記した感じで結構使いますよ？ 「駄目ってさんざ言ったんに～」とか「教師なんにそんな事も知らんとな･･･」とか

Comment: ^ へえ・・・中国地方かどこかの方言ですかね・・・

Comment: @someone 標準語や（全国的に流通する）新東京方言にないものはその旨を注記すべきかと思います。

Comment: 方言としても聞いた事があるような気もしますが言っている様に単なる発音のブレだと思いますが？自分も砕けた口調にしたい時に使いますし。 因みに私は東京(23区西部)方言しか知りません。

Comment: そうですか。失礼しました。・・